# Update the powerpoint chart's data from the selected range in excel

Tags: vba, charts, powerpoint

Can anyone please help me with the code? Im looking to create a macro where I can  update the Powerpoint's chart from the data selected/copied in the excel file. Below are the following steps to understand my request well:

1. New data are available in excel file. I will the select/copy the data
2. Charts are existed in the powerpoint, but the data are old. Need to update only the data which are copied/selected in the excel file using VBA automations.

Below are my code, pls assist.

```
Sub update_Chart()

Dim myDocument As Variant
Dim myChart As Variant

Dim Wb As Object
Dim App As Object

Dim clipboard As MSForms.DataObject
Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
      
Set myChart = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Chart
myChart.ChartData.Activate
Set Wb = myChart.ChartData.Workbook
Set App = Wb.Application

clipboard.SetText ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
clipboard.PutInClipboard
Wb.Close (0)
End Sub
```

Now the above code does not able to update the new data.

Comment: Sounds that you're reinventing the wheel here. PowerPoint already has a way to link a chart from Excel

Comment: Thanks for comments, But I do not want to link the charts, just need to update the value of the charts from the selected data in the excel.

Comment: Pls [edit] your question and add some sample data, names/ranges from where you want to update the data and the charts' IDs in PowerPoint.